# InfoPath 2010 - Change Field value on open

Tags: infopath2010

I have an InfoPath form field that currently uses a default value to set it to the current user name when the form opens, but I need it to re-set that field if a different user opens the form later on. Is there a way to tell InfoPath to change the value of that field every time the form is opened?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a rule to be executed everytime the form opens. Do the following:

1. Go to the "Data" tab.
2. Click on the "Form Load" button to add a new rule.
3. On the Rules pane edit the rule so the action is "Set a field's value"
4. Edit the field and value.
5. To set the logged in user as value, click on the Insert Function button and select "username" under the "User" section.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the separate list for those username in your site, if so use people picker control, in that control set the action rule by querying the username from data connection and match that name with the username log in